# Overriding Spring XML Configuration

Tags: xml, spring, configuration, overriding

I have a base context file and an junit context file that overrides beans for testing purposes.  I am trying to block initialization of an object in the base context with a mock.

The bean in the base context is a Spring RmiProxyFactoryBean and I dont want it to open connections during testing.  The junit context is overriding this with a mock.  However, Spring is still initializing both objects.  How do I prevent the object in the base context from being initialized?

base-context.xml:

```
<beans>
  <bean id="BaseObj" class="org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiProxyFactoryBean" lazy-init="true" />
</beans>
```

junit-context.xml:

```
<beans>
  <bean id="BaseObj" class="com.blah.RmiProxyMock" />

  <import resource="classpath:spring/base-context.xml"/>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use spring profiles for doing that, for example read this article http://blog.chariotsolutions.com/2012/01/spring-31-cool-new-features.html